# Order the table by Month and year chronologically

Tags: php, mysql

In actual database I have Upload date as 'Month'.  In this query I want to order the table by Month, Year chronologically. But on dashboard for every page refresh order changes.

```
$sql2="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Month,'%b %Y') as MonthYear,SUM(Target) AS MonthTarget,Sum(DeliveredTillDate) AS MonthDelivered, (Sum(Target)-Sum(DeliveredTillDate)) AS MonthDeficit FROM spiceworks.dashboard WHERE ClientName='Spiceworks' Group By MonthYear order by MonthYear desc LIMIT 4; ";

$mnthresult = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);


<table class="table table-hover" style="font-size: 12px;">
 <thead>
       <tr>
          <th >Month</th>
          <th>Target</th>
           <th >Delivered</th>
          <th >Deficit</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
         <?PHP 
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($mnthresult)) 
            {      
                echo "<tr>
                         <td >".$row["MonthYear"]."</td>
                         <td >".$row["MonthTarget"]."</td>
                         <td >".$row["MonthDelivered"]."</td>
                         <td >".$row["MonthDeficit"]."</td>
                 </tr>";
            }
        ?>

  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: what is your current result?

Comment: Month Target Delivered Deficit
Jul 2018  4531 534          3997
May 2018  760 0          760
Jun 2018   2714 30          2684
Apr 2018   407 250          157

Comment: Your `order by` is invalid. Try `order by MonthYear desc`.

Comment: But it gives sequence as (May, June, July, Apr) instead of (july, june, may, apr)

Comment: Then adjust the value of `MonthYear` in your `select`. You can order only by something that is part of your `select`. Otherwise you will get something unpredictable. If I tell you to count the number of phone numbers on each page of a phone book and order that result by the last digit of the phone number, you would not know how to order it (but that is basically what you asked MySQL to do).

Comment: Thank you.  This issue is solved.  I have done some changes in a query and then used 'order by MonthYear desc'.